# Project ARKit + SwiftUI + Different layout preview/simulator

Tags: swiftui, realitykit

I cannot understand why in the simulator the layout is different from the layout displayed in xcode/preview.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
            ARViewContainer()
            Text("hello")
        }
    }
}
```

here the screenshots:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; I don't know why your simulator and preview don't match, but I do know why it's appearing the way that it is on the device. Are you getting any errors in the debug?

Any container views in SwiftUI will only take up the required space that they need. they will also distribute according to your settings. For example, you have a ZStack that contains a bottom alignment. You also have a ARViewContainter() that takes up a portion of that stack. They are aligned behind each other on the `Z` axis where the text is in front and the other container is behind. A quick way to prove this and test it is to include a background shape behind everything for example.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle().edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                   .foregroundColor(Color.red)
        //Your Views 
    }
}
```

This will force the ZStack to take up all available space and your other views should then align as expected. Basically, your `Text` is aligning to the bottom of the maximum provided space, which is being provided by your `ARViewContainer()`

#### Further Reading and Understanding

- Views only take up the space required for what's in them, unless otherwise specified.
- ZStacks operate on the `Z` axis, forward/backwards.

In your case you have a view with a set size called ARViewContainer() which takes up the width of the screen and a portion of the height. Since it's the largest view you have, the ZStack inherits that size.

Your text is smaller than the ZStack so the ZStack does NOT inherit the size. You do however have a `.bottom` assignment. So your text is over your `ARViewContainer()` and aligned to the `.bottom` edge of that container.

Finally the ZStack is centered in the remaining space available, giving it the impression that your `.bottom` isn't doing anything, when in reality it is.

#### Reproducing the Issue

Here is a code snippet that reproduces your issue and makes it a bit clearer and easier to understand.

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.yellow).frame(width: 100, height: 100, alignment: .center)
        Text("Test")
    }
}
```